# How do you make a square element symbol (\in), to show that an element belongs to a collection of set?

Tags: symbols

I was reading a book the other day and they distinguished between the usual element symbol (\in) and an element symbol to show that a set is a member of a collection of sets. For the latter they used a square element symbol that looked similar to a wide E. Does anyone know what the code for this might be? The book,says it was prepared with regular LaTeX. Thanks.

The Symbol is

[image]

Comment: Where can we see the symbol in question? Can you add a link to your question?

Comment: this symbol appears to be in unicode, at U+22FF, with a meaning "z notation bag membership".  (it doesn't seem to be identified by detexify.)  check the stix or xits fonts.  if this isn't what you are looking for, with a published reference i can submit a request for addition to unicode.

Comment: @BarbaraBeeton As of 2018, ⋿ is in both `unicode-math` and `stix` as `\bagmember`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just superimpose a minus to `\sqsubset`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\newcommand{\sqin}{%
  \mathrel{\vphantom{\sqsubset}\text{%
    \mathsurround=0pt
    \ooalign{$\sqsubset$\cr$-$\cr}%
  }}%
}
\begin{document}
$a\sqin A\sqsubset B$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is very helpful. Could you please add code to generate the symbol for the negation of square set membership, the analogous square counterpart to the symbol generated by the code `\not\in`?

Comment: Never mind, I've figured it out on my own: I simply added the command `\not` in front of both occurrences of the command `\sqsubset` in your code.